# Android SharedPreferences- accessToken just change everytime i login and other service

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hey guys so I built sharedpreferences which JWT Token saved. and then I want to GET information from another api service using request header(Content-Type and **accessToken**).

It gets 404( err code. Because accessToken in SharedPreferences are not the same as even though i made that api service right after login service(that JWT Token save)
Dontknow why

```
        fun loginService(email: String, password: String) {
            val loginService = AuthApiService.create()

            loginService.logIn(LoginRequestDto(email,password))
                .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponseDto> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<LoginResponseDto>,
                        response: Response<LoginResponseDto>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val loginResponse = response.body() ?: return

                            //save token
                            App.prefs.token = loginResponse.data.accessToken

                            //get token
                            //val token = App.prefs.token

                        } else{
                            Log.v("fail!!","fail")
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponseDto>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.d("f!!", t.localizedMessage!!.toString())
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "server X", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })
        }
        loginButton.setOnClickListener {
            val id = idEditText.text.toString()
            val password = passwordEditText.text.toString()

            // 아이디와 비밀번호가 빈 경우
            if (id.isEmpty()) {
                showErrorMessage("아이디를 입력해주세요.")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            if (password.isEmpty()) {
                showErrorMessage("비밀번호를 입력해주세요.")
                return@setOnClickListener
            }
            loginService(id,password)
            val intent = Intent(this, setgetActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            //finish()
        }
```

```
//the problem api 

fun getSet() {
            val settingService = AuthApiService.create()
            settingService.getSetting()
                .enqueue(object : Callback<AllSettingResponseDto> {
                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<AllSettingResponseDto>,
                        response: Response<AllSettingResponseDto>
                    ) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val issettingResponse = response.body() ?: return
                            t.text = issettingResponse.data.nickname
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this@setgetActivity,
                                "${issettingResponse.data}",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                            Log.d("OK", "${issettingResponse.data}")
                        } else {
                            Log.d("bad request", "?")
                        }
                    }
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<AllSettingResponseDto>, t: Throwable) {
                        Log.d("No Internet", t.localizedMessage.toString())
                    }
                })
```

```
//SharedPre

class Prefs(context: Context) {
    private val prefName = "tokenPref"
    private val prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(prefName,MODE_PRIVATE)
    var token:String?
        get() = prefs.getString("token",null)
        set(value) {
            prefs.edit().putString("token",value).apply()
        }

}
```

```
//Interceptor 

class InterCeptor:Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val req =
            chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("accessToken", App.prefs.token ?: "").build()
        return chain.proceed(req)
    }

}
```

In that HttpLoggingInterceptor, the problematic api service's body comes first.(and then login's body) is that related?

Thanks.

postman server test

Comment: Use commit() instead of apply() and check!

Comment: it didntwork .... error says there is no token value anyways thank you malik!